# Opening a modal with force:recordEdit throws "Invalid Record Id or Record not accessible," but then it works?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, modal

**The issue:** when opening a modal with a `force:recordEdit` inside of it, the modal briefly flashes **"Invalid Record Id or Record not accessible."** and then allows me to proceed editing the record. I think it may be because I am not initializing something properly, because the error only appears for 1 second or so before it disappears on its own.

[image]

The component has an `aura:iteration` over a list of records, and when a record is clicked, the record Id is passed to the JS controller using the HTML5 data attribute, set as a component attribute, and the modal is displayed, with recordId set to the Id of the record that was clicked.

My markup and code follows, if anyone has any idea why this might be happening, I would be forever grateful!

Component:

```
<aura:component controller="ReasonabilityParametersController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId">
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.clientSideAction}" value="{!this}" />

    <aura:attribute name="parameters" type="Reasonability_Parameter__c[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="currParamId" type="Id" />

    <!-- ####This is the hidden modal with the force:recordEdit#### -->

    <div class="slds-container--fluid">
        <div aria-hidden="false" id="editPanel" role="dialog" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open" style="display:none;">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
                    <force:recordEdit aura:id="edit" recordId="{!v.currParamId}" />
                </div>
                <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" onclick="{!c.save}">Save</button>       
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- ####This is the iterator#### -->

        <aura:iteration items="{!v.parameters}" var="currParam" indexVar="index">
                <div data-record="{!currParam.Id}" onclick="{!c.showEditPanel}">
                    <lightning:button label="Edit"  />
                </div>
        </aura:iteration>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    clientSideAction : function(cmp, event, helper) {
        var action = cmp.get("c.getParameters");
        action.setCallback(this, function(data) {
            cmp.set("v.parameters", data.getReturnValue());
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },

    showEditPanel : function(component, event, helper) {
        var selectedItem = event.currentTarget;
        var recId = selectedItem.dataset.record;
        component.set("v.currParamId", recId);
        document.getElementById("editPanel").style.display = "block";

    },

    save : function(component, event, helper){
       component.find("edit").get("e.recordSave").fire();
       document.getElementById("editPanel").style.display = "none";
   }
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came upon this thread having the same exact issue. The problem is, is that the first time it pops up, there is not a valid id set on the edit object, hence the error message. What I did was put a div around the edit object as such:

```
<div aura:id="editDiv" class="slds-hide">
    <force:recordEdit aura:id="editStatus" recordId="{!v.selectedId}"/>
</div>
```

Notice I added the slds-hide class so that this is hidden initially. Now, within my controller popup method, I have:

```
cmp.set("v.selectedId", id); //id retrieved earlier
setTimeout(function()
{ 
    var ec = cmp.find("editDiv");
    $A.util.removeClass(ec, 'slds-hide');
}, 800);
```

This gives it time to load up the edit object before displaying. There may be a better way, but this seems to be working for me so far. Good luck!!

Answer (score 1):

@Brett, I tried your answer and it doesn't work for me. I ended up replacing `<force:recordEdit>` with Lightning Data Service.

Also... I think this is important... I changed from hiding the component with the style to using `<aura:if>`.  That way, the component doesn't get drawn until it has a recordId.

Here's the code, works great.

COMPONENT

```
<aura:attribute name="editActive" type="boolean" default="false"/>


<!-- Edit Payment Modal -->
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.editActive}">
    <div class="slds-container_fluid">
        <section>
            <div aria-hidden="false" id="editPanel" role="dialog" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open" style="display:block;">
                <div class="slds-modal__container">
                    <header class="slds-modal__header">
                        <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" title="Close">
                            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
                        </button>
                        <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">Edit Payment</h2>
                    </header>
                    <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium">
                        <force:recordEdit recordId="{!v.paymentId}" aura:id='edit'/>
                    </div>
                    <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                        <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" onclick="{!c.save}">Save</button> 
                        <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" onclick="{!c.cancel}">Cancel</button>     
                    </footer>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</aura:if>
<!-- End Edit Payment Modal -->
```

CONTROLLER

```
    cancel: function(cmp, event, helper)
    {
        cmp.set("v.editActive", false);
    },

    save : function(cmp, event, helper){
        cmp.find("edit").get("e.recordSave").fire();
        cmp.set("v.editActive", false);
        helper.refreshView(cmp, event, helper);
    },
```